# passing HTML element as an arguvment to a function vs. using getElementById to get same element

Tags: javascript, function, design-patterns, getelementbyid

When defining a function how do you decide if the function will get HTML elements passed as an argument or use `getElementById` instead? Is one way faster than the other? I know that having things passed as an argument increases the re-usability but it's sometimes hard to for see whether function is going to be used in another piece of code.

Just to clarify instead of using `getElementById` I would have something like this `<input type="text" name="colour" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally it doesn't make much difference if you call getElementById before you call the function, and pass the result, or from within the function. There is a modicum of extra flexibility by passing in an element to the function because you can then also use other selectors (besides just id) to find your element.

Comment: I have never seen calling getElementById from outside the function, can you give an example of how this would be done? Your talking about in the input field itself right, or what?

Comment: You would essentially be getting your element, then passing it into the function. This can be done in-line like this: `var myFunction(element){ // do something; }; myFunction(getElementById('myElementId'));`. Or you coud save it as a var and pass the var to your function; `var myElement = getElementById('myElementId'); myFunction(myElement);`

Comment: is the second way any better than `myFunction(this.value)` if it is being called from an input field?

Comment: if `this.value` is a selector id, then it's a matter of layered functions. The input field is calling a function that would then call `myFunction()`. It's essentially the same as the second example., just a matter of where you make the call to `getElementById()`. Practically speaking they're very very subtly different, but will perform roughly the same. I would only recommend separating this out to two separate layered functions if you want to call `myFunction()` from somewhere else as well from the field, like to react to a different event.

Comment: So in summary `getElementById()` is always called at some level to get the value of an element. The only difference is when/how it is called?

Comment: you got it. If it's at all an option I'd look into using jQuery to accomplish this type of thing. It abstracts a lot of the nastiness away and gets the element for you.

Answer (score 2):

To be flexible, you can make functions that can take either:

```
 function whatever( element ) {
   if (typeof element === 'string')
     element = document.getElementById( element );
   // ... do stuff ...
 }
```

Comment: I'd give you plus two, if I could.  This is a great solution.  In certain circumstances, either could certainly be beneficial.  Without specifics, this looks pretty close to ideal.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan it can get a lot fancier, if need be.  This is just the proof-of-concept :-)

Answer (score 0):

Always pass the object, not the ID. Passing the object is like giving you a book. Passing an ID is showing you the name of a book, then putting the book back in the library and asking you to find it.

There's no reason to search for the element every time.